# Ajax Jquery function params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

i have this code that is working, but i want to make more generic.

This code submit a Form with Ajax, and get this json:

**{"message": "Verifique todos los campos","success": "false"}**

depends of success or no add a class to my #MESSAGE-DIV, So i want to pass to the funcion

#MESSAGE-DIV, instead to be harcoded

```
var frm = $('#loginForm');
frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {                                            
            if(data['success'] == "true") {
                alerta = "alert alert-success";
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV" ).removeClass( "alert alert-error" )
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV" ).html(data['message']).addClass(alerta);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '/stockrecetas/';
                }, 3000);
            } 
            else {
                alerta = "alert alert-error";
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV" ).removeClass( "alert alert-success" )
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV" ).html(data['message']).addClass(alerta);
            }    

        },
        error: function(data) {                    

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

this is my HTML form:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="2EDW4oyrAPToDObfiaXQO95oFOGM9H5B">              
    <div id="MESSAGE-DIV"></div>
    <label for="id_username">Username:</label><input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text">
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">                          
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? I am having a hard time understanding your question. Also, have you tried anything already? Where did you run into a problem? Or are you asking about general advice?

Comment: I have two forms, one to register and one to login.

I want to show error message or success.

and do not want to rewrite all the code, just changing the name of the DIV I use to display the message.

and do not want to rewrite all the code, changing the name of the DIV I use to display the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like James Lai said me, I made a function witch recibes the parameters and sends to de .ajax()

SOLUTION:

```
function genericForm (form, messagediv) {
    var frm = form;
    frm.submit( function () {

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {                                            
                if(data['success'] == "true") {
                    alerta = "alert alert-success";
                    $(messagediv).removeClass( "alert alert-error" )
                    $(messagediv).html(data['message']).addClass(alerta);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '/stockrecetas/';
                    }, 3000);
                } 
                else {
                    alerta = "alert alert-error";
                    $(messagediv).removeClass( "alert alert-success" )
                    $(messagediv).html(data['message']).addClass(alerta);
                }    
            },
            error: function(data) {                    
            }
        });
        return false;


    });


   };
```

so i call the function in this way:

```
    var frm1 = $('#registerForm');
    frm1.submit(genericForm(frm1, "#MESSAGE-DIV1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a nice function which accepts your selectors passed as parameters:

```
function submit(formEl, messageEl) {
    $(formEl).submit(function() {
        // ...
        $(messageEl).removeClass("alert alert-success");
        // ...
    });
});
```

(The formEl was just there to generalize this even more)

Comment: How should i call this function?